# Chef with a secured couchdb

Tags: authentication, chef, couchdb

I've installed chef , which uses couchdb.
It worked fine until i've secured couchdb by creating an admin user in couchdb giving and setting require_valid_user = true in default.ini as written here: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html

Now i get a 401 Network error: Connection refused, most probably because of the newly created user.

Any idea where i can set the new admin username /password for chef to access the couchdb?

Answer (score 0):

Oldie but goodie, answering for completeness sake, as it's still a valid question.

When specifying a user/pass in the couchdb config, you mush now provide those credentials to Chef Server, in the form of changing the `couchdb_url` parameter in the server's config file `/etc/chef/server.rb`, as per the source [here](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/10-stable/chef/lib/chef/config.rb#L156).

This may look like:

```
couchdb_url "http://<username>:<password>@localhost:5984"
```

You must restart the Server services for this to take effect.

NOTE: Chef 11 has since been released, and CouchDB is no longer used in this version.